# Diamond and silver rings.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

$2$ diamond rings and $4$ silver rings cost $\$1440$. 
A diamond ring and a silver ring cost $\$660$. 
How much does a silver ring cost?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Say one diamond ring costs $d$ and one silver ring costs $s$.  What equation does the first condition give?  What about the second?

Answer (score 0):

How much do two diamond rings and two silver rings costs?

Can you subtract that from the first equation, leaving only two silver rings?

Answer (score 0):

Let the cost of a diamond ring be $x$ and the cost of a silver ring $y$.

Now

$2x+4y=1440$

$x+y=660$

Solve this system of equations for $y$.